# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Имею ошибку
Error!: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. [20018] (severity 16) [(null)]

Имею код

```
try {

$user = "usname";
$pass = "password";
$host = "host";
$dbname = "dbname";

$DBH = new PDO("dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
/*foreach($DBH->query('SELECT * from card_peoples') as $row) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($row);
    echo "</pre>";
}*/

$STH = $DBH->prepare('INSERT INTO table (PEOPLE_ID, DIVISION_ID, SEX, MARRITAL_STATUS, LANG, BIRTHDAY, PHOTO, SOURCE, NOTES, UPDATE_DATE, F_NAME, M_NAME, L_NAME, FULL_NAME, INN, FLAGS, DELETED, LOGIN, TEXT_PASSWORD, EXTERNAL_CODE, GROUP_ID, UNPAY_TYPE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_A, ATTRIBUTE_B, GUID, TRANSACT_GUID) values (:PEOPLE_ID, :DIVISION_ID, :SEX, :MARRITAL_STATUS, :LANG, :BIRTHDAY, :PHOTO, :SOURCE, :NOTES, :UPDATE_DATE, :F_NAME, :M_NAME, :L_NAME, :FULL_NAME, :INN, :FLAGS, :DELETED, :LOGIN, :TEXT_PASSWORD, :EXTERNAL_CODE, :GROUP_ID, :UNPAY_TYPE_ID, :ATTRIBUTE_A, :ATTRIBUTE_B, :GUID, :TRANSACT_GUID)');


$peopleid = "1";
$divisionid = "1";
$sex = "1";
$marrital_status = "1";
$lang = "1";
$birthday = "1";
$photo = "1";
$source = "1";
$notes = "1";
$update_date = "1";
$f_name = "1";
$m_name = "1";
$l_name = "1";
$full_name = "1";
$inn = "1";
$flags = "1";
$deleted = "1";
$login = "1";
$text_password = "1";
$external_code = "1";
$group_id = "1";
$unpay_type_id = "1";
$attribute_a = "1";
$attribute_b = "1";
$guid = "1";
$transact_guid = "1";

$STH->bindParam(':PEOPLE_ID', $peopleid);
$STH->bindParam(':DIVISION_ID', $divisionid);
$STH->bindParam(':SEX', $sex);
$STH->bindParam(':MARRITAL_STATUS', $marrital_status);
$STH->bindParam(':LANG', $lang);
$STH->bindParam(':BIRTHDAY', $birthday);
$STH->bindParam(':PHOTO', $photo);
$STH->bindParam(':SOURCE', $source);
$STH->bindParam(':NOTES', $notes);
$STH->bindParam(':UPDATE_DATE', $update_date);
$STH->bindParam(':F_NAME', $f_name);
$STH->bindParam(':M_NAME', $m_name);
$STH->bindParam(':L_NAME', $l_name);
$STH->bindParam(':FULL_NAME', $full_name);
$STH->bindParam(':INN', $inn);
$STH->bindParam(':FLAGS', $flags);
$STH->bindParam(':DELETED', $deleted);
$STH->bindParam(':LOGIN', $login);
$STH->bindParam(':TEXT_PASSWORD', $text_password);
$STH->bindParam(':EXTERNAL_CODE', $external_code);
$STH->bindParam(':GROUP_ID', $group_id);
$STH->bindParam(':UNPAY_TYPE_ID', $unpay_type_id);
$STH->bindParam(':ATTRIBUTE_A', $attribute_a);
$STH->bindParam(':ATTRIBUTE_B', $attribute_b);
$STH->bindParam(':GUID', $guid);
$STH->bindParam(':TRANSACT_GUID', $transact_guid);


$STH->execute();


} catch (PDOException $e) {
  print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
  die();
}
```

Как я понял нужно конвертировать, но как это сделать и что конвертировать не ясно. Саму таблицу на сервере не посмотреть. т.е делать приходится всё в слепую. 
процедура через `$STH = $DBH->prepare();` ?

Comment: дак `photo` небось картинкой надо заливать, не? и что это за разработка такая, когда нет доступа к бд? на край выполните запрос, который вам покажет структуру таблицы